# Deadlock on Merge replication

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, merge-replication

I'm having a really confusing problem on the msmerge_contents table on some
of my merge replication databases. It seems I'm receiving a dead lock on the exact
same row on the same index on the table msmerge_contents.
Here is the deadlock xml i'm currently seeing. Based off what i can tell
the index name: 1 means clustered index (looking at the associated objid).
So it is same i/o path and the row hashid is the same (b5f70c321dc6) which is the same row.
One process is the msmakegeneration that i believe the merge agent runs (every minute in this case) and the other process is the trigger that gets call (every time requests table gets updated). Could anyone shine a light on this issue, I'm still learning deadlocks and to me this doesn't make sense. Thanks

```
<deadlock-list>
    <deadlock victim="process8f31f9498">
        <process-list>
            <process id="process8f31f9498" taskpriority="5" logused="2616" waitresource="KEY: 20:72057594653704192 (b5f70c321dc6)" waittime="1925" ownerId="3680081779" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2012-10-05T10:02:01.223" XDES="0x8f3b283a8" lockMode="U" schedulerid="7" kpid="11784" status="suspended" spid="252" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="-5" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2012-10-05T10:02:01.177" lastbatchcompleted="2012-10-05T10:02:01.177" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.177" clientapp="GN-SQL-GW_National-GW_National Publicati-vz-sql-59" hostname="GN-SQL" hostpid="19364" loginname="DCSINFOSYS\SQLServer" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="3680081779" currentdb="20" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673384544" clientoption2="128024">
                <executionStack>
                    <frame procname="mssqlsystemresource.sys.sp_MSmakegeneration" line="337" stmtstart="29568" stmtend="29880" sqlhandle="0x0300ff7fa885d0f97c6e5901f39f000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
update dbo.MSmerge_contents with (rowlock) set generation = @target_gen 
                where generation = @gen and tablenick = @art_nick     </frame>
                </executionStack>
                <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 32767 Object Id = -103774808]    </inputbuf>
            </process>
            <process id="process87f1e4188" taskpriority="0" logused="676" waitresource="KEY: 20:72057594653704192 (b5f70c321dc6)" waittime="1994" ownerId="3680083804" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2012-10-05T10:02:01.363" XDES="0x38b50b6a8" lockMode="X" schedulerid="3" kpid="3920" status="suspended" spid="93" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2012-10-05T10:02:01.210" lastbatchcompleted="2012-10-05T10:02:01.210" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.210" clientapp="National KBM R1 Gateway" hostname="HQ-GATEWAY" hostpid="9592" loginname="DCSINFOSYS\GatewayBot" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="3680083804" currentdb="20" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673319008" clientoption2="128056">
                <executionStack>
                    <frame procname="GW_National.dbo.MSmerge_upd_A5AC5485C2484F3C9BFC2CE7057DE6B4" line="97" stmtstart="8470" stmtend="9582" sqlhandle="0x03001400d6e21f3c4265d200d5a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
update MSmerge_ctsv_A5AC5485C2484F3C9BFC2CE7057DE6B4 with (rowlock)
        set lineage = { fn UPDATELINEAGE(lineage, @replnick, @oldmaxversion+1) }, 
            generation = @newgen, 
            partchangegen = case when (@partchange = 1 or @joinchange = 1) then @newgen else partchangegen end, 
             colv1 = NULL  
        FROM inserted as I JOIN MSmerge_ctsv_A5AC5485C2484F3C9BFC2CE7057DE6B4 as V with (rowlock)
        ON (I.rowguidcol=V.rowguid)
        and V.tablenick = @tablenick
        option (force order, loop join)     </frame>
                    <frame procname="GW_National.http.StoreTransaction" line="66" stmtstart="3658" stmtend="3968" sqlhandle="0x03001400f6be377e130a2c019c9e000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE
        Requests
    SET
        StatusMessage = @StatusMessage,
        GatewayVersion = @GatewayVersion
    WHERE
        SubTransactionUUID = @GatewayTransactionGuid     </frame>
                </executionStack>
                <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 20 Object Id = 2117582582]    </inputbuf>
            </process>
        </process-list>
        <resource-list>
            <keylock hobtid="72057594653704192" dbid="20" objectname="GW_National.dbo.MSmerge_contents" indexname="1" id="lock888cc6e00" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594653704192">
                <owner-list>
                    <owner id="process87f1e4188" mode="U"/>
                    <owner id="process87f1e4188" mode="X" requestType="convert"/>
                </owner-list>
                <waiter-list>
                    <waiter id="process8f31f9498" mode="U" requestType="convert"/>
                </waiter-list>
            </keylock>
            <keylock hobtid="72057594653704192" dbid="20" objectname="GW_National.dbo.MSmerge_contents" indexname="1" id="lock888cc6e00" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594653704192">
                <owner-list>
                    <owner id="process8f31f9498" mode="S"/>
                    <owner id="process8f31f9498" mode="U" requestType="convert"/>
                </owner-list>
                <waiter-list>
                    <waiter id="process87f1e4188" mode="X" requestType="convert"/>
                </waiter-list>
            </keylock>
        </resource-list>
    </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

Comment: You might want to remove your table names and user accounts from the code you provided.

Answer (score 2):

This lock [compatibility matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186396%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) can shed some light. Note if granted mode is `S` (shared read), transaction requesting for `U` (can update) will be granted access. Also note same is true other way, i.e. U is existing lock and request for S is granted. `X` (Exclusive access )is not compatible with neither `S` not `U`.
Also `U` is not compatible with `U`

i.e.

```
Existing Requested Status
S U Yes
U S Yes
U U No
S X No
U X No
```

In your two different transactions first acquire S or U on same resource. Then some time down the line they want to convert the current lock to more exclusive lock. Here is one possible order which can result in above deadlock.

```
T1 : Request S
SQL : Granted.
T2 : Request U
SQL : Granted (because U is compatible with S)
T1 : Convert from S to U. (lock escalation)
SQL : Wait. T2 is holding U.
T2 : Convert from U to X (lock escalation)
SQL : Wait. T1 is holding S. (DEADLOCK!!)
```

To resolve this deadlock don't do conversion of lock. Try to get most exclusive lock first. i.e T1 should straight go for U and T2 should go for X

In your case

```
<owner id="process8f31f9498" mode="S"/>
<owner id="process8f31f9498" mode="U" requestType="convert"/>
```

Where as

```
<owner id="process87f1e4188" mode="U"/>
<owner id="process87f1e4188" mode="X" requestType="convert"/>
```

Let me know if you have any questions.